# Дуб и лопух — как символы глупости

Tags: лексика

Помните бессмертный диалог: "Дуб! Как слышно? Прием. Лопух не догадался?"
Интересно, почему именно эти растения олицетворяют глупость? Точнее, "лопух" — это, скорее, раззява, а дуб — тупой, недалекий.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лопухами действительно называют простых, неопытных, доверчивых людей, которых очень легко обвести вокруг пальца. Интересно, что под словом "лопух" имеют в виду чаще большие листья этого растения. Тут близко и слово "лопоухий" (уши большие, как листья лопуха). Про доверчивых еще говорят "уши развесил".

Само же растение и его плоды - репей/репейник.  Интересно, что здесь уже другая "характеристика". Говорят "приставучий, как репей" про человека, от общества которого трудно избавиться.

С дубом сложнее. Много статей о дубе, его значении в культуре, сказаниях и проч. Везде отношение к дубу серьезное и почтенное. 
   Но есть и такие выражения, как "дубина" или "дубина стоеросовая" применительно к человеку глупому, непонятливому. Первоначально "дубина" (палка, палица) не исключено, что была из дуба.

А сам диалог очень удачный. Дуб, насколько я помню, по фильму фамилия. А еще раньше позывные типа "дуб", "береза" и проч. действительно были. Здесь здорово обыграли и "дуб", и "лопух".

Comment: Думаете, фамилия? По-моему, скорее, прозвище. Или, даже скорее, позывной.)))

Answer (score 4):

О ком говорят ***"лопух лопухом"***? — не о глупом(дураке), а о простоватом, недалёком человеке, простофиле:
*" Мне уж сравнялось шестнадцать, но я рос лопух лопухом… Я окончил школу и поступил учеником в зеркальную мастерскую, но не особенно убивался на работе, так что пользы от меня было мало"* (И. Гуро. Женщина-змея).
Здесь значение слова "лопух" очень близко к сравнению с растением лопух - сорное растение, выросшее где и как попало, пользы мало и вид неприглядный, простой(о медицинском использовании не говорим).

*Конечно, докторша удивилась невероятно, слушала, стукала, снимки разглядывала… А я стою перед ней лопух лопухом и ничего не могу объяснить* 
 (И. Степанова. История без болезни) — внешне  слишком прост, простофиля, не понимает, потому что в ступоре, похож на необразованного, ниже окружающих по умственным способностям и знаниям.

[**Лопух**](http://eslovar.com.ua/malyiy_akademicheskiy_slovar/page/lopuh.26529/) *прост.* О простоватом, несообразительном человеке.
*— Лопух он у тебя, Чего проще велосипед купить, а и то никак не сообразит.*
(Грибачев. Вечереет)
Отсюда ***"лопухнуться"*** — совершить промах, непродуманный поступок, ошибиться,  оконфузиться, оплошать, опростоволоситься...

А вот **ДУБ** — символ крепости (из-за крепости древесины и корней) и могущества.
А что такое могущество? Это твердость своих взглядов, подкрепленная какими-то материальными ценностями(корни и древесина у реального дуба). И не всегда такие взгляды можно переубедить.
***«Тупой как дуб»*** — нет возможности изменить его точку зрения, так могуч, что до него не достучишься. Это если рассматривать именно «тупой как дуб», а не «тупой как пробка».

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, что дуб, как могучее растение, медленно реагирует на внешние раздражители –  например, не так быстро, как другие, раскачивается от сильного ветра. Это качество мы переносим на людей, которые имеют замедленную реакцию. Человек, может быть, и не глупый, даже поумнее других, но очень раздражает холериков, которые медлительность мышления непременно связывают с глупостью. А дальше детали забываются, и вот мы уже не можем понять, почему уважаемое растение становится символом глупости.

Лопух – предмет ПЛОХО ОБУЧАЕМЫЙ и, соответственно, малообразованный. У него, как и у дуба, замедленная  реакция на внешний мир, и это не идет ему на пользу. Он прост, доверчив, простодушен, излишне навязчив там, где ему не рады.  И внешность у него соответствующая –   сорная трава с большими листьями.  Короче, не умеет он жить, поэтому и стал символом  недалекого  и неразвитого ума, который легко поддается любому обману.